# Android Glide - BitmapTransformation() cannot be applied to (android.content.Context)

Tags: android, android-glide

I try to crop an image inside recyclerview adapter:

This is the code:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .transform(CutOffLogo(context))
    .into(holder.image)
```

This the class:

```
public static class CutOffLogo extends BitmapTransformation {

    public CutOffLogo(Context context) {
        super(context); // HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform,
                               int outWidth, int outHeight) {

        Bitmap myTransformedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                toTransform,
                10,
                10,
                toTransform.getWidth(),
                toTransform.getHeight() - 20);

        return myTransformedBitmap;
    }
}
```

First error is on static:

```
Modifier 'static' not allowed here
```

When I change it to abstract then I get

```
Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
```

on `.transform(CutOffLogo(context))`

Then I get `'BitmapTransformation()'` in

```
'com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapTransformation' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)'
```

on `context` in `super(context)`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Static class

You are receiving error:

```
Modifier 'static' not allowed here
```

And it is true. Only nested class can be static - so class inside another class.

Where can we use it?

A static nested class may be instantiated without instantiating its outer class.

## Abstract class

Java Abstract class is used to provide common method implementation to all the subclasses or to provide default implementation. But you can not create instance of this class.

## Fix - `CutOffLogo` class

1) It is not necessary to call constructor. You can remove this call.

2) In latest version ofthe Glide you need also `updateDiskCacheKey()` method.

So your class can look like there. In **Kotlin**:

```
class CutOffLogo : BitmapTransformation() {
    override fun transform(
        pool: BitmapPool,
        toTransform: Bitmap,
        outWidth: Int,
        outHeight: Int
    ): Bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(
            toTransform,
            10,
            10,
            toTransform.width,
            toTransform.height - 20
        )

    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {}
}
```

Or in **Java**:

```
public class CutOffLogo extends BitmapTransformation {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(
            @NotNull BitmapPool pool,
            @NotNull Bitmap toTransform,
            int outWidth,
            int outHeight
    ) {

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
                toTransform,
                10,
                10,
                toTransform.getWidth(),
                toTransform.getHeight() - 20);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(@NonNull MessageDigest messageDigest) {

    }
}
```

## Fix - calling Glide

When you are using **Java**, you have to use:

```
.transform(new CutOffLogo(context))
```

but in **Kotlin**:

```
.transform(CutOffLogo(context))
```

Comment: I'm using Kotlin, there is never new at creating objects. JAVA is only the class and I can't find it in beautiful Kotlin

Comment: @Pikaboo updated answer. Added transformation in Java and Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks I don't get any errors, but the image isn't getting cropped. But this has to be a new topic. Android is a complete piece of garbage